# How can I simply access a packet's payload and modify it?

Tags: networking, snort

I am attempting to access a packet's payload and modify it with a word (let's say Bob).

I have a simple tunnel VPN program written in C that displays packets in plain-text. When I connect to a host, I want to grab the packets, either rewrite or add to the payload the word Bob, then send it.

I am trying to implement this as simple as possible, as I am barely learning encryption and networking.

Can a program like Snort do this?